# Is n/(log(n)) considered polynomial time?

Tags: big-o

Not exactly sure if this is considered polynomial or something else. Couldn't find the exact example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because it is upper-bounded by a polynomial (n).

Comment: Upper bounded? O(n) > O(n/log(n)), do I just ignore the denominator because it grows so much slower than the numerator?

Comment: As long as n is greater than the base of the logarithm, n > n/log(n).  So n is an upper bound on n/log(n) for sufficiently large n.  From the wikipedia page, "An algorithm is said to be of polynomial time if its running time is upper bounded by a polynomial expression in the size of the input for the algorithm".